# HP 4210G DHCP relay

Tags: dhcp, hp, 3-com

I have an HP 4210G, which is a rebranded 3com 4200G.  I have set up DHCP relay on the switch, but I'm only able to select one server group aka one IP at a time. Is it possible to set up multiple DHCP servers?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Section "Correlating a DHCP Server Group with a Relay Agent Interface" in the [3Com Switch 4210G Family Configuration Guide](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/action.process/public/psi/manualsDisplay/?sp4ts.oid=4218284&javax.portlet.action=true&spf_p.tpst=psiContentDisplay&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.prp_psiContentDisplay=wsrp-interactionState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02586078%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) states that:

> You can specify up to twenty DHCP server groups on the relay agent and
>   eight DHCP server addresses for each DHCP server group.
>
> A DHCP server group can correlate with one or multiple DHCP relay
>   agent interfaces, while a relay agent interface can only correlate
>   with one DHCP server group.

The command to create a DHCP server group is:

```
dhcp relay server-group group-id ip ip-address
```

I have no 4210G to test, but I guess running this command several times with the same group ID and the IP addresses of your DHCP servers will add the servers to the group. For instance:

```
dhcp relay server-group 10 ip 10.10.10.1
dhcp relay server-group 10 ip 10.10.10.2
dhcp relay server group 10 ip 10.10.10.3
```

And then you apply the  server-group to the interface.

**EDIT:**

Finally, I have found [a configuration example](http://blog.patricknielsen.net/2012/01/hp-h3c-switches-dhcp-relay.html) for H3C switches with the same syntax stated in the 4210G config guide and using a sever group with 2 servers:

```
dhcp enable
dhcp relay server-group 1 ip x.x.x.x
dhcp relay server-group 1 ip y.y.y.y

interface vlan-interface 1
dhcp select relay
dhcp relay server-select 1
```